# Manually select artifacts and create a build using Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, artifacts

Here is what i am trying to achieve:
We have a SVN repository, but we dont want to promote all the changes we get via svn update!
I want to manually select each artifact and then build it via Jenkins and deploy it.

Any plugin which will allow me to do that? I dont have a simple criteria like exclude *.jar or *.xml but it is purely manual human intervention.

Thanks,
Zoom

Comment: The most important question - what is your project type? Maven, Ant or freestyle (but then - which tools exactly)? It might be possible, but need more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about making a new job with build parameters. One of the parameters could be a svn tag/branch to build/run/use, then have a build step that runs a script. In the script you can do whatever you wish with that svn tag, including a checkout and build.

Or, if you want to use pre-built artifacts from another job, you can specify links to those artifacts in the build parameters or a job name/number and have the script automatically grab them for you.

Many different ways to run a job manually :)